# Converting systemd script to .init script for CentOS 6

Tags: shell, server, scripting, centos, systemd

I'm not really good with shell scripting, by not really good I mean I don't know it at all.

I need to convert this systemd unit file to a .init script, it's for setting up nginx and uwsgi for serving a web-app.

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

CentOS 6 does not support systemd, please help.

Answer (score 0):

In systems that don't support `systemd` you could use other [supervisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision), for example, if need something portable and also compatible with macOS/BSD you could use [immortal](https://immortal.run/).

This is a basic [`run.yml`](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/) that could start `uwsgi`:

```
cmd: /home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
cwd: /home/user/myproject/myprojectenv
log:
    file: /var/log/my-project.log
```

You could also check the [uWSGI examples](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html?highlight=init) from the docs, `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` for example:

```
# simple uWSGI script

description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

exec uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --socket :3031 --wsgi-file /var/www/myapp.wsgi
```

In this case, is using Upstart, check this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/292000/94862